# Are there any resources or forums online for helping me understand TAOCP?

Tags: satisfiability, education

## Context

I am doing an undergrad math project that involves exploring Donald Knuth's "TAOCP, Volume 4, fascicle 6: Satisfiability".

I am having trouble parsing some of this material.

Surely there are some online forums where different sections are unpacked or discussed or translated into Python?

I googled this but cannot find anything that helps me.

## Question

What are some online resources to help people parse TAOCP?

Surely many people have read this work before me?

Comment: This fascicle is actually quite new, so I doubt there is extensive commentary on it.

Comment: People might be able to direct you towards more appropriate resources for you if you can pinpoint exactly what it is you are struggling with.

Comment: For a rough overview (and some of that perspective may help orient you wrt the book), you may also want to look at talks that Knuth gave about satisfiability [in 2016](https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/news16.html), as he was finishing up work on this fascicle: at [SIAM Meeting in July](https://www.pathlms.com/siam/courses/3028/sections/4140/video_presentations/31340), and at [Brown University in December](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4lhrVPDUG0). But yeah, it would be better to say exactly what you're struggling with (or even post separate questions here or each difficulty you encounter).